# javascript redirect not working anyway

Tags: javascript, html

There are many same questions here. I tried all solutions - nothing helps.

I want to open new page in some tab with javascript. Here is my HTML:

```
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script src="functions.js"></script>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>
<body>
...
<label>
<input type="image" name="imageField" id="loginClient" onclick="testUrl()" src="images/index_33.gif" />
</label>
...
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my functions.js:

```
function testUrl()
{

window.location = "content.html";

}

function loginClient()
...//more functions
```

I tried other ways too:

```
window.location.replace("content.html")

top.location="content.html"

window.location.assign("content.html")

window.open("content.html", "_self")

window.location.href="content.html"

window.event.returnValue = false;
window.location = "content.html";

setTimeout(function(){window.location.assign("content.html");return false;},500)
```

nothing works, I tried it in Opera, Firefox (all in Windows) and Chrome (Debian).
BUT it works if I set:

```
window.open("content.html")
```

but in new tab, isn't solution, I need it in same tab.

BUT if I try to debug it with Firebug and click always "Step into" than all solution work. And if I set alert() before redirecting, it works too.

Console shows no errors.
I have no idea, help.

RESOLVED: Thanks to @lonesomeday!

this is the solution:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#loginClient").click(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      window.location = "content.html";
    });
});
```

Comment: You want to open a link in the same tab where you are, on the same page???

Comment: Works for me. Check that your `functions.js` file actually being included (e.g., path is right).

Comment: Is your input #loginClient inside a form?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You've got this `onclick` attribute on an `<input type="image">` element. Image inputs are effectively `submit` buttons. When you click it, it is activated, and the form is submitted. When a form is submitted, it cancels any ongoing HTTP requests, such as your `window.location` call.

So you need to prevent the form submission from going ahead.

The quick and dirty way to do this is to return `false` from your event handler. Something like this:

```
onclick="return testUrl()"
```

With the JS:

```
function testUrl()
{
window.location = "content.html";    
return false;
}
```

The prettier way to do this would be to bind your event handlers with Javascript and use `event.preventDefault`.

Comment: This is only the case if the `input` is inside a `form` element. What the OP has works otherwise, and doesn't show a `form` per se...

Comment: @JaredFarrish It is in a `form` element. Otherwise it would work. The `form` element is plainly contained in `...`.

Comment: The input is in form element. I tried return false; just now - doesn't work